# How to convert a webview as PDF and share the PDF file with other applications?

Tags: flutter, dart

Here is my webview

```
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
        child: WebviewScaffold(
      url: weburl,
      withZoom: true,
      hidden: true,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('View ' + type),
        actions: [
          IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.print), onPressed: () {}),
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: _bottomTab(),
    ));
  }
```

Step 1: I have a webview in my Flutter application and I want to save the webview as PDF file. After changing into PDF file I need to share that file among other applications.

Step 2: I have to download a file from webview as a PDF format.

Comment: https://devbybit.com/flutter-generating-pdfs-in-flutter/ did it resolve

Comment: @Muhtar i don't understand the example because that creating a table and saving it and converting into pdf

Comment: my question is i want to convert a webview url into a pdf file later i want to share that file